# Package name 'OPERATORLER' part should not start with an uppercase letter

Tags: kotlin

What exactly does this mean? How to write package names.

"Package name 'OPERATORLER' part should not start with an uppercase letter"

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kotlin [Documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#naming-rules) Says:

> Names of packages are always lowercase and do not use underscores (org.example.project).

In programming languages, it is best practice to use lowercase letters or **camel case notation**  for package names, variable and function names. Generally, you should avoid multiword names. But always remember, class names should always start with a capital letters. These rules are not necessary to follow but it is for your convenient thats why IDE recommend this.I should recommend to follow best practices for naming conventions and all other things.

Comment: Some other languages have different conventions; but yes, the convention for Java and Kotlin is for class/interface/object/enum names to be in ‘PascalCase’, field/property/method/function/parameter/variable/label names to be in ‘camelCase’, and package names to be entirely in lower case.  If you don't, it'll compile OK, but other developers will find it confusing to read.  (just AS iT Would bE In eNgLiSh…)